# PHP OOP force child class to see parent class properties

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to use child class properties in parent class but i can't get a result. I'm using constructor in child class. Maybe someone could explain, how can i do this? I will leave some commented code below. Thanks!

```
Class DataBase extends Main {

    public $email, $password1, $password2;

    function __construct($email,$password1,$password2) { //this is my child class with properties

        $this->email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $this->password1 = mysql_real_escape_string($password1);
        $this->password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password2);

    }
}

Class Main{} //this is my parent class. I want to use DataBase class properties here.
```

**EDITED** Last question was hell wrong.

Comment: Yes, and...? Just use `$this->email` in your child...!?

Comment: Every member that is defined protected or public will be accessible in the child class. Only private members can't be accessed directly

Comment: O gosh, i did it wrong. All i want is make parent class to extend child class parameters ;x.

Comment: @EvaldasButkus : If want that kind of relation, u should store the instance of the `Database` as a member of the `Main` class. Do mind `Database` should not extend `Main` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your properties as public you should be able to access child properties in your parent class as you always use the real object in PHP. However, this is a just an awful thing to do that in OOP. If, you have another child class, you may not have these properties. It is a pure OOP antipattern.

**EDIT:**

When you do `$obj_suc = new Main($input_email, $input_password1, $input_password2);` you instantiate the class `Main`. The resulting object `$obj_suc` don't know anything about the class `DataBase`. Absolutely nothing. If you want to instantiate the class `DataBase`, you have to do `$obj_suc = new DataBase($input_email, $input_password1, $input_password2);`.

If you want us to help you refactoring, we need a little more code from `Main` and `DataBase` (like 1 method using the child properties for instance). We also need the code where you do `$obj_suc = new Main($input_email, $input_password1, $input_password2);`.

Comment: My main problem is that i can't access child class methods if i set object through parent class instance. So i decided to set object through child class, but now my parent class can't see child class properties. Maybe you have a suggestion?

Comment: Your parent shouldn't access your child properties. Show me your original code and give me the constructors of both classes (if there is one for both of course). Note that you cannot instantiate a `DataBase` class using `$main = new Main();` so in this case you won't have any properties of `DataBase`.

Comment: I got only 1 constructor in child class as in my question and none in parent class. I set instance like this $obj_suc = new Main($input_email,$input_password1,$input_password2); and i can reach my parent class methods, but whenever my parent class method requires value from child class (which i made through constructor) i'm getting an error. I ques i have to refactor my code. But still have no idea how.

Comment: could i contact you via e-mail? if you are ready to help.

Comment: Of course, my email is on my github which is in my profile. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access those variables easily as they have the access modifier "public" which means they are globally accessible. e.g.

```
<?php

$dbc = new Main( 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' );

echo $dbc->email, ' ', $dbc->password1, ' ', $dbc->password2, PHP_EOL;
```

This snippet would work fine

Edit : I would also like to add that an active MySQL connection or available MySQL resource would be required to use the mysql_real_escape_string function.

Comment: An object of `Main` in not an instance of `DataBase`. An object of `DataBase` is an instance of `Main`. You should use `$dbc = new DataBase( 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' );` instead of `$dbc = new Main( 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' );`. Moreover I think the question is about accessing a child property in a parent class, not only to access a public property.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code to something more like this :

```
<?php
   class Foo {
      public $var1, $var2;

      public function __construct($v1, $v2) {
         $this->var1 = $v1;
         $this->var2 = $v2;
      }
   }

   class Main {
      private $foo = null;
      public function __construct(Foo f$) {
         $this->foo = $f;
      }
      public function getChildMembers() {
         if ($this->foo == null) return;
         return array($this->foo->var1, $this->foo->var2);
      }
   }

   $foo = new Foo('Bar', 'FooBar');
   $main = new Main($foo);
   var_dump($main->getChildMembers());
```